Is it possible to generate RSA key pairs using a seed (deterministic) in Swift?
I know it is possible to generate them randomly using a library like SwiftyRSA, but if I wanted to generate an RSA keypair deterministically using a mnemonic seed, would this possible?
I've looked everywhere and can only find threads about openSSL self compiled lib which AFAIK does not provide a deterministic generation for RSA keys.

Hi, and welcome to Stack overflow! Do you want to get the same key every time? Please clarify your use case, it will help us help you. I would suggest that the thing that needs this feature should instead generate a random key pair, and something else send it the secret encrypted with that thing's public key. That secret could be a private key, but most likely a symmetric key. That connection should be authenticated, not a small problem, but you already have it when you would send the mnemonic seed - in the clear. Lookup multiparty Diffie-Hellman key exchange for example.

In other words: let's get the crypto right, then we'll look at the libraries to implement it.

I want to be able to generate the same key given the same seed. The reason why is because I want to be able to recreate these keys on a different platform given the same seed without sending it via API.

Then the seed is the key. Whoever has the seed can create the key. You still have to distribute the seed, might as well distribute the key.

In essence yes, the seed is the key. But I'd still like to use the RSA algo of key generation so that the format of the keys are the same on both platforms without distributing the keys. My original question is still whether or not a deterministic RSA key generator exists for Swift

Highly unlikely, as it is bad crypto and provides no security. For the sake of discussion, I guess you could play tricks with the random number generator (used to pick RSA's p and q at random) so it always give out the same key. But you would be taking the long way home to making your system insecure. Just hardcode the key and use the time you saved to deal with the security incidents this will create.

It is technically possible to generate RSA keys deterministically from a seed. After all, you can do it by taking an algorithm that generates an RSA key randomly, and replacing the random generator by a pseudorandom generator. If you use the same seed for the pseudorandom generator, you get the same key.
However, RSA key generation is a pretty complex process that uses randomness in a brittle way. In particular, it contains a loop that looks like this:

Generate a random number p.
Perform a complex test using heuristics to determine whether p is (pseudo-)prime.
If p is not satisfactory, try again, i.e. go to step 1.

If you make any change to the heuristics in step 2, the resulting key is different, since a candidate might not be rejected at that stage (but it might still be rejected later). So most implementers do not provide an interface to derive an RSA key deterministically from a seed.
I'm not familiar with SwiftyRSA, but I expect that it's typical in not providing deterministic RSA key derivation.
You aren't going to have an actual “mnemonic” seed for an RSA key anyway. A seed should be 256 random bits. Nobody is going to remember that. If you're going to write it down, you might as well write down the RSA key.
If having a shorter seed is really important, use ECIES instead of RSA. Deriving elliptic curves determinstically is easy, so it's more common to have this feature in libraries. (But I don't know anything about crypto libraries in Swift.) Also, an ECC private key is only 256 bits (unless you need resistance against fundamental mathematical improvements), so you might as well transmit a 256-bit private key rather than a 256-bit seed. Using derivation from a seed is useful if you need to derive multiple keys from the same seed.
